# React Redux rerenders whole list on single object attribute change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I've a list (immutable.js) in my store containing multiple objects.
This list is displayed in a component as a table with rows. Those rows are subcomponents displaying one single object. One attribute of those objects should be editable. So onChange() i dispatch an action which should change the attribute of that one specific object. As we should never ever change the state, i return a whole new list with just that single object changed. But because the whole list is a new list object, the table component gets updated every single change. this leads to a really slow working app.

I've just looked at the official [todo app example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos) and inspected it with the Perf addon. Realising that they also rerender the whole todos-list on every change (mark as completed, unmark). How am I supposed to fix that?

Comment: Do you mean "rebuild all the DOM" or calling the "render" method? the second case is normal, but the virtualDOM know what element DOM he will rerender

Comment: Please show your code. It will be much easier to help if we can see how you are doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest factors that will impact your list rendering performance are heavy rendering cycles and expensive DOM mutations. Make sure that your list items are as efficient as possible when they re-render. Done properly, this will make a big difference.

You have a couple of straight forward options.

1. Break your rows out into their own component (if not already done) and optimize the render and update cycle.
2. Use a library such as [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) to help with list/table/grid performance.

Comment: My rows are own components and `@connect`ed to the store.
But Perf tells me, that the connect(rowComponent) "component" is rerendered x times and therefor wasted.

Comment: @Marc You need to optimize the render cycle of those components to short circuit the update cycle. Check out https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: I know but how should I compare them?
The parent component (table) rerenders itself because the list is now another object. And if the Table rerenders itself the connect(rowComponent) rerenders itself, too. the rowComponent does not rerender, but the connect(rowcomponent) and the application is really laggy

Comment: @Marc Are you saying with your first comment that you have a smart component for each row that has it's own @connect? If so that would cause some serious performance problems itself. Since the rows are repeated they should be dumb components.

Comment: yes they are since they need to dispatch. You mean i should pass the dispatch function down to the row component?`
Thank you a lot! I just forgot about that since i'm working with redux!

Comment: @Marc yeah if you are repeating a component it will be dumb and just render props/fire actions you give it (if they need to dispatch, pass them the action they need). You should not connect 100 items if you have 100 rows, that would effect your performance. You only want smart components and connect at the top level of things.

Comment: thank you very much!
that was the part i was missing. Makes much more sense!

Comment: Since I edited it like ajmajmajma suggested and changed the store only onBlur and not onChange its much faster. But still the whole app is rerendered, as the store changes. It's no a performance problem, but there is still time wasted